# How to use "show more" on a page or post to show and hide content

Tags: jquery, read-more

What if you want to use the built-in "WYSIWYG"-button `show more`, to hide and show text within a post or page?

I started out with misunderstanding the function. I thought the function was actually meant for what I needed, namely hiding part of the content on load, with a "read more" button that would show the remaining content after clicking it.

However, this didn't appear to be the case, which made me search for a solution to use it anyway. You could say, to use it in the way I wanted it to work.

Since I couldn't find a solution online, I had to start developing my own solution, which with just a bit of jQuery turned out exactly as I wanted.

**Note** If you use the read-more tag as it was intended (to show what part of the text had to be shown as a teaser on the frontpage/archive etc.), you won't be able to use this solution just as is. There is, however, an easy fix to this with a bit of HTML, which I will add to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Is this some self promotion or what? WPSE is not some where you can put a blogposting because it could be informative.

Comment: I had a question, but instead of asking it, I found a solution. That's a function within Stack Exchange: Answer your own question. I have no idea how this should be self promotion, but hey, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Charles Share your code and make others also happy with your knowledge. It will give you a great feeling, try it :)

Comment: @Charles Please take a moment to familiarise yourself with this help center entry [Can I answer my own question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Any post containing a "read more" tag, had a `<p>`-tag with inside a `span` with an `ID` called `more-#`, where the `#` could be any number.
It looks like this:

```
<p>
   <span id="more-1"></span>
</p>
```

I had to select that specific span, and stored it within a variable:

`var $showMore = $('span[id*="more-"]');`

To add some kind of text to the `show more`-span, I used jQuery's `.html()`:

`$showMore.html("Read more <i class='icon-down-open-big'></i>");`

Of course, anything **AFTER** the `read more`-tag had to be hidden on load, which can be done by going up one level (by using `.parent()`) and then selecting all the following blocks within that parent. This can be done with `.nextAll()`, which selects all the blocks after the current one (of course until the parent-block closes).

Since this selection is going to used later on, I also stored it within a variable:

`var $showMoreNext = $showMore.parent().nextAll();`

Now we had all selectors, all we needed to do is hide it on load, and show it when `Read more` is clicked.

`$showMoreNext.hide(); // to hide all elements after the Read more tag`

```
$showMore.on('click', function() {
   $showMoreNext.toggle("slow");
});
```

The `toggle` makes it possible to click on the tag again, and hide all the originally hidden content.

So, all that's needed to make an accordion-like expansion after Wordpress' inbuild "read more"-tag, is the following bit of jQuery:

```
var $showMore = $('span[id*="more-"]');
$showMore.html("Læs mere <i class='icon-down-open-big'></i>");
var $showMoreNext = $showMore.parent().nextAll();
$showMoreNext.hide();

$showMore.on('click', function() {
  $showMoreNext.toggle("slow");
});
```

**Now, what if you actually use the "read more"-function already?**

There are two possible solutions:

1) You include the above jQuery only on the pages where you want to "abuse" the "read more"-tag
2) You make a small bit of html that you place in your text on the spot you wish. Just make sure you adapt the jQuery accordingly.